# Can this piece of metal be straighten after an accident...?

Tags: honda, accident, frame

I was involvedin a front collision accident and my left side had some damage(headlights, hood, brackets etc..) Car drove fine and alignment was correct and no mechanical problems.

The biggest worry for me is those two bent body panels that I have circled. Can these be straighten...?? They got bent inward after the accident. Any educated guess on worth not worth it or price to straighten...??

[image: 2013 Honda Accord Frame]

Comment: Yes, No, Maybe... will depend on the skill, the damage and your money... Replacement is also an option.

Comment: Do they actually have those frame parts for sale..?

Comment: @Noah - In most cases you'd have to buy the frame parts from an auto salvage yard, then graft them into the existing frame. Not for the faint of heart. You *really* gotta know what you're doing to accomplish it.

Answer (score 4):

All depends on how badly they are bent and if they are structural or not. Some body shops can pull a bent frame back into shape if it's not too badly bent. This frame will be functional but almost certainly weaker than it was. You will need to check local laws as some places will not be happy about you driving a vehicle around with structural damage.

Usually insurance companies will consider the vehicle a total loss if it has any real frame damage.

A picture might help working out if it's fixable or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be straighten, however that is really bad idea. In my country usually insurance count the car as 'totaled'(dead, out of order, beyond repair), because such damages weaken one of most important parts of car's body. Damage to car body frame usually means weaken structure of the car.If there is another font end collision you might get seriously hurt(even die) because of weak frames on the front.
There are plenty for services that would straighten this up, however I don't recommend driving such car for your own safety.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be straightened.  You'll need some serious equipment to ensure it's done properly.  It isn't something you'd be able to beat back into shape by eye using a hammer.

That said, you'd find that most professional bodyshops wouldn't try and straighten them but instead would chop the out of the shell and replace them by welding in a new section.

As regards if it's worth it or not, we can't really provide an answer on that.  This isn't a shopping advice site.  You'd be best speaking to a few local bodyshops, any shop worth its salt will likely want to see the vehicle to assess the damage.  Only after you've got a few prices will you know yourself if it's going to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously avoid doing this if I were you; These are here to absorb impact in the event of a crash as well as provide structure to the vehicle.

That end of the car will implode the next time it's hit, likely resulting in much more serious injuries / could cause a fatal injury.

If there's not a way to replace those parts (Hell, see if you can't have them removed and somehow a replacement welded on if they don't come out), scrap the car for safety.